# end_date (str) - how can I add another function like "cmd.run: date" to end_date module function to get the actual date?

Tags: command-line-interface, salt-stack

This is my command below and it says **"true"** but doesn't work.

```
end_date=cmd.run 'echo %date:~10,4%/%date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2%'
```

Comment: How/where are you running this assignment to variable? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is a salt execution module, since the module end_date only can take string as a parameter where I should set the date e.g: 2022/04/04, but in this case I want to add another function to that module where I get the date on system via cmd.run function. I want to know if it's possible somehow by maybe doing this in another way?

Comment: This isn't valid Python, so how are you writing this execution module? What's the rest of the file?